# Request to run MapBasic 10.5 code in MapBasic 9.1 version

Tags: mapbasic

I have created MapBasic code using 10.5 version. Now I have to run in a lower version (9.1).

Please anyone help me how to do this...

How to copy paste the program code from 10.5 version to 9.1 version?

Comment: According to research I found that you need to recompile the code in an older version of MapBasic (v9.0 or earlier), no other way around it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not used any new MapBasic function above version 9.1, you could try and open the MBX in a text editor. Change the number in the second line:
!Version 1005 to !Version 910

Comment: Note that if you try this you should make a backup of the original file first, and use a more sophisticated text editor than Windows Notepad which will corrupt the file on saving. Notepad++ will save the edited file correctly.